# HTML class declaration

Tags: html

I am using html and things work well.
so when keeping a ID, I have div Class= "xxx"

but I see in some of the sample files as:

```
div class="xxx yyy zzz";
```

when it is defined like this what is the id? how to read this ?
If you can point me to documentation also it would be great.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm), it explains about multiple classes.

I don't seem to understand the id part of your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: Frank, The url you provided is very helpful and it cleared all my qs

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, that is simply a `div` with three separate class names, "xxx", "yyy" and "zzz". An element can have as many class names as necessary.

From the [HTML5 spec for the `class` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#classes):

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

The div does not have an id.  It has 3 classes assigned to it: xxx, yyy, and zzz.
[W3Schools - CSS Id and Class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) would be a good resource to look at

Comment: Unfortunately, W3Schools is [not usually a good resource](http://w3fools.com) to look at.